# MYSQL timestamp conversion

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp

I haven't been able to find a conversion for the format the timestring I have.  I need to convert this string into a timestamp.

2016-06-10T19:59:00.833996032Z

Sorry I know this has been answered before I just haven't understood how to do it in my specific case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f')x;
+----------------------------+
| x                          |
+----------------------------+
| 2016-06-10 19:59:00.833996 |
+----------------------------+
```